# Retrieve data from child table using parent table LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, join, inner-join

I need to retrieve data from a child table. The parent table has a one to many relationships with the child table.

parent table = taskSchedule

child table = notes

Notes model

```
public class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NotesInfo { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateCreated {get; set;}
    public TaskSchedule taskSchedule {get; set;}
    public User user { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; } 
}
```

TaskSchedule Model

```
public class TaskSchedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; }     
}
```

I need to be able to return back all the notes connected to a specific task. Furthermore, I need to return back only the tasks related to a specific user.

The current code returns back the tasks related to a specific user.

```
       public async Task<IList<TaskSchedule>> GetTaskSchedulesByUser(int UserId)
    {
        var userTaskSchedule = await _context.TaskSchedules
            .Where(u => u.userId == UserId)
            .ToListAsync();                                   

        return userTaskSchedule;            
    }
```

I need to be able to return back the notes related to those tasks as well.

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple inner join suit your needs here?
(untested, but this is the general idea behind a LINQ inner join)

```
var userTaskSchedule = await _context.TaskSchedules
.Join(_context.Notes, schedule => schedule.Id, note => note.Id, (schedule, note) => new { schedule, note })
.Where(u => u.schedule.userId == UserId)
.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Yes, an inner join seems like the way to go, however, I'm struggling to get an inner join to work.

Comment: what is your outcome if you implement the above example? An inner join will only show rows that have a record in each table

Comment: I ended up using the .include statement 

var userTaskSchedule = await _context.TaskSchedules
                    .Include(ts => ts.Notes)
                    .Where(u => u.userId == UserId)
                    .ToListAsync(); 

I was told not to use joins while using entity framework as it creates the joins automatically.

Comment: Good call, I was going to recommend trying the .Include next as that is the way to join the tables automatically, provided you have the keys configured. In an instance where you didn't have any relationships defined, the .Join syntax would have worked. Glad you got it sorted out.